# React-Native - How to convert JS to TS using functional component declaration (FC)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, pendo

I've to implement Pendo's React Native implementation in TypeScript. My App.tsx has following code that has to modified to accommodate Pendo's methods in it:

### Current App in TS:

```
export const App: FC = () => {
  const [isInitialized, setInitialized] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const init = async () => {
        ... some code ...
    };
    init();
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      {isInitialized ? (
            <NavigationContainer
              theme={combinedTheme}
              linking={linking}
              onReady={SplashScreen.hide}
            >
              ... code ....
            </NavigationContainer>
      ) : null}
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
};
```

### Pendo's Suggested Implementation in JS:

Pendo's implementation is in JavaScript, and I've not been able to find a custom type definition for the library. Here is the relevant segment in the documentation for initializing Pendo in React Native with React Navigation:

```
import {withPendoRN} from 'rn-pendo-sdk'
import {useRef} from 'react';

function RootNavigator(props) {
  const navigationRef = useRef();
  return (
    <NavigationContainer 
      ref={navigationRef}
      onStateChange={()=> {
        const state = navigationRef.current.getRootState()
        props.onStateChange(state);
      }} 
      onReady ={()=>{
        const state = navigationRef.current.getRootState()
        props.onStateChange(state);
      }}>
      {MainStackScreen()}
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
};

export default withPendoRN(RootNavigator);
```

### My Modified App in TS:

How can I modify my existing code to integrate Pendo in it? This is what I've done so far to the `App.tsx` file:

```
export const App1 FC = () => {
  const [isInitialized, setInitialized] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    
    const init = async () => {
       ... code ...
    };

    init();
  }, []);

  const navigationRef = useRef<any>();
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      {isInitialized ? (
            <NavigationContainer
              ref={navigationRef}
              theme={combinedTheme}
              linking={linking}
              onStateChange={()=> {
                const state = navigationRef.current.getRootState()
                prop.onStateChange(state);
                console.log(Children);
              }} 
              onReady ={()=>{
                const state = navigationRef.current.getRootState()
                props.onStateChange(state);
                SplashScreen.hide;
              }}
            >
               ... code ...
            </NavigationContainer>
      ) : null}
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
};

export const App = withPendoRN(App1,null);
```

My main questions are:

1. Does my `App()` provides equivalent implementation to `function RootNavigator(props)`  from Pendo's instructions?
2. Is my implementation for `onStateChange()` and `onReady()`inline with Pendo's instructions?
3. Is there a Pendo's React Native implementation available in TypeScript that I can review?

When I run the application in emulator, it doesn't crash or log any errors, however, Pendo's startup messages to confirm its valid install is missing from my logs.

Comment: Your code has several issues. Seems like you're not calling `SplashScreen.hide`, if that's supposed to be a method, in your Modified App (TS). You probably need to call it `SplashScreen.hide()`. You have `props.onStateChange(state)`, but I don't see `props` defined anywhere. You need to have them as a parameter of your `App1` component: `export const App1: FC = (props) => { ...`. And why are you using `App.onStateChange(state);` in your `onStateChange` callback property? Isn't that supposed to be `props.onStateChange(state);`?

Comment: @Kapobajza You are spot on for `props`. Please ignore `SplashScreen.hide` as I have that implemented elsewhere. Back to `props`, how can this be defined and what can be its type?  `App.onStateChange(state)` is a typo that I've corrected to `prop.onStateChange(state)`. What can I do to define `props` here?